# remove duplicate lines across multiple txt files

Tags: awk, sort, duplicate

I have 12 text files all in one folder, each with about 5 million lines, each file has no duplicate line on its own but there are duplicated across multiple files, I want to remove the duplicate lines in each file but still save them separately, I have tried many Linux sort command and it keep merging the file together, I have Windows, Linus, and Mac, Is there any code or application that can do this?

Comment: You say "remove duplicates in each file" -> Does that mean that the line should still be present once, or should all lines that appear more than once be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove all duplicates but keep the first one which seen first in a file and remove from the other files, you could use awk as following, this also preserve the order of lines.

```
awk '!seen[$0]++ { print >FILENAME".new" }' file1 file2 ... file12
```

not much necessary here to close the open files by awk as it would be maximum 12 files, but you can still close() them after each file processed and finished.

```
awk '!seen[$0]++ { 
    if(prev!=FILENAME) close(prev".new");
    print >FILENAME".new";
    prev=FILENAME }
' file1 file2 ... file12
```

---

you can use shell and external command `mv` then to rename the output files to original name (you could use [`rename`](/q/19654/72456) command as well):

```
for file in ./*.new; do echo mv -v -- "$file" "${file%.new}"; done
```

Note: remove the `echo` if you were happy with the result.

---

if you have GNU awk, you can use `-i inplace` option to modify the files inplace and simplify the whole command as following:

```
gawk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' file1 file2 ... file12
```

Comment: I want to keep line that appear once, this code works well, thanks, but now i need to remove .new in front of my files.

Comment: @SurpriseAwofemi see the update; also please add [this clarification](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686377/remove-duplicate-lines-across-multiple-txt-files/686383#comment1297472_686383) into the [body](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686377/72456) of your question